# runat server additional attribute only work in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, runatserver

```
<cc2:FindEntity ID="feCiudad" runat="server" DataKeyField="id" 
   DataTableName="tbl_ciudad" TextBoxDisplayField="descripcion" 
    Width="315px" NoFoundMessage="No existe"></cc2:FindEntity>
```

Server side

```
Protected Sub btnGuardar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       
   Handles btnGuardar.Click If feCiudad.SelectedValue <> Nothing 
      Then ... In IE the selectedValue is != null 
      but in other browsers always is null
```

I add dynamically an attribute (SelectedValue="1") in client side but in the post the value becomes null at server in Firefox,Chrome but in IE becomes 1 at server.

Why? :(

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code, and then delete the comment.

Comment: From what I understand, you add it with javascript, and this javascript works only on IE. Please post that javascript code that fails.

Comment: @Aristos i add it with javascript but the javascript don't fail, fail in btnGuardar_Click feCiudad.SelectedValue is null but in IE feCiudad.SelectedValue hava the correct value.